# Android notification from my planner

Tags: android, events, calendar

I have build a Planner app using SQLlite to store reminders and my code, no API. Next logical step is to get notified when my database has rows for the day. This would imply a background query on phone startup or on phone date change or whatever (I am totally new to this). Perhaps scheduling alarms for every day of the year is not the best solution.
Can someone kindly point me to right direction or a tutorial?

Comment: use adnroid alarm manager service. Schedule hourly/min/daily/monthly/yearly, ect.

Comment: Do you mean schedule an alarm for every days containing an entry in DB? In a year could be 365 alarms?

Comment: I found exactly what I was looking for here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fV9NmvxXJo and here https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html